# Ubuntu 18.04 rebooting my Lenovo Yoga 920

Tags: suspend, lenovo

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS on a Lenovo Yoga 920. Things are fine, except that (quite regularly?) when coming back to my laptop, I discover that it has rebooted. I am assuming that it happens now and then when the laptop goes in sleep mode, although I (by definition of the problem) have never been there when the reboot happens.

Does anyone know what could be the reason for that? I know this is a bit scarce in details, but I don't really know what other information to include.

Here is the result of `uname -a`:

> Linux canonne-yoga 4.15.0-45-generic #48-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 29 16:28:13 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

**Edit:** as it turns out, it looks like (1) nothing is logged in /var/log/syslog when this happens; (2) this really is due to the "blank screen (after inactivity)" setting, since setting it to "Never" appears, so far, to have prevented it to happen again.

Comment: Your syslog (at /var/log/syslog) will record the reboot. Look in syslog for timestamps *before* the reboot. If Ubuntu is triggering the reboot, there will be an entry in the log.

Comment: Some BIOS have an option to start back up after a power loss; it's possible this is being triggered, and might not necessarily have something to do with your OS.

Comment: @user535733 I don't see anything:
``Feb 23 13:14:13 gnome-software[3960]: no app for changed ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
Feb 23 13:14:13 gnome-shell[1476]: g_array_unref: assertion 'array' failed
Feb 23 13:17:27 systemd-modules-load[299]: Inserted module 'lp'
Feb 23 13:17:27 kernel: [    0.000000] microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0x96, date = 2018-05-15
Feb 23 13:17:27 kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 4.15.0-45-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-031) (gcc version 7.3.0 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)) #48-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 29 16:28:13 UTC 2019 (Ubuntu 4.15.0-45.48-generic 4.15.18)``

Comment: @Minty why would it be triggered, though? (This happens both while plugged or unplugged, and with 80+% battery)

Comment: If your laptop lost power because of a hardware fault this feature might be triggered, such as a bad battery or faulty power supply.

Comment: @Minty Ah... How can I check that?

Comment: First thing would be to access your BIOS and see if the feature is enabled in the first place. It'd likely be under the power profiles. Should be something called "Restore after loss of AC power" or something similar.

Comment: @Minty After checking, there doesn not seem to be anything like that (nor even a "Power" tab or anything resembling it) in the Lenovo BIOS.